# How to solve error 405 method not allowed, for django graphql server and react axios in front end

Tags: python, django, reactjs, graphql, axios

Hi I am having hard time to solve this problem i have django `graphql` server which is running for my local machine port `8000` when I query it in insomnia everything works well but I am integrating with front-end `reactjs` and `axios` i am getting error:

```
xhr.js:178 OPTIONS http://127.0.0.1:8000/graphql/ 405 (Method Not Allowed)[enter image description here][1]
```

My `settings.py` from Django `graphql` server

My front-end request from `ReactJs` using `Axios`:

```
export function getProducts(args = {}) {
  return (dispatch) => { // optionally you can have getState as the second argument

    dispatch({type: HOME_GET_PRODUCTS_BEGIN});

    const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const query = {
        url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/graphql/',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          "Accept": "application/json",
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        data: {
          query: `products{
                  userKey{
                  id
                  username
                  email
                  password
                }
                id
                title
                price
                image
              }
          `,
      },
    };
    axios(query).then(
      (res) => {
        dispatch({
          type: HOME_GET_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS,
          data: res.data,
        });
        resolve(res);
      },
      // Use rejectHandler as the second argument so that render errors won't be caught.
      (err) => {
        dispatch({
          type: HOME_GET_PRODUCTS_FAILURE,
          data: { error: err },
        });
        reject(err);
      },
    );
  });

return promise;
  };
}
```

please I need help

Answer (score 0):

This looks like problem in your CORS. As you see, client sends `OPTIONS` instread of `POST`. This is so-called *preflight check* performed by browser for any *unsafe* method request, if domain, host or port of page is different from endpoint.

If this is the case, use [django-cors-headers](https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers), and add 127.0.0.1 to list of allowed hosts.